# passing two argument in subquery

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to pass 2 argument in sub query.my query is working if I pass static variable in subquery.I want to pass dynamic value in sub query.I want to pass $status in  subquery.Is it possible to pass two argument in subquery as `(function($query,$status) {}`

**working**

```
DB::table('asset_status_tracker')->where('asset_status_tracker.request_id','=',$request_id)->where(function($query) {
     $query->where('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','17')->orwhere('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','20');
   })
   ->select('asset_status_tracker.status_after')->first();
```

**not working**

```
$status='17';
DB::table('asset_status_tracker')->where('asset_status_tracker.request_id','=',$request_id)->where(function($query,$status) {
     $query->where('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=',$status)->orwhere('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','20');
   })
   ->select('asset_status_tracker.status_after')->first();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass your variables to [closure/anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) function you can do like `function($query) use ($status)`

```
$status='17';

DB::table('asset_status_tracker')
    ->where('asset_status_tracker.request_id','=',$request_id)
    ->where(function($query) use ($status) {
         $query->where('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=',$status)
               ->orwhere('asset_status_tracker.status_after','=','20');
  })->select('asset_status_tracker.status_after')
   ->first();
```

Similarly for more variables you can pass them as

```
function($query) use ($var1, $var2, ....)
```

Comment: Also no need to add table name for column as there is no other table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your variable to read `$status = 17;` with no quotes.